# Is socat broken at the moment?

Tags: socat

I attempted to run socat on Windows 10, however when executed it showed the following error:

```
0 [main] socat 5536 find_fast_cwd: WARNING: Couldn't compute FAST_CWD pointer.  Please report this problem to the public mailing list cygwin@cygwin.com
```

Googling the error seems to show that this is due to an old version of Cygwin being used. However after I installed the most recent version of Cygwin the same error popped up. I tried removing the cygwin DLLs in the socat folder in order for socat to hopefully grab the DLLs from the installation folder but that did not work as it seems the names of the DLLs (and their version) are hardcoded. Is there a workaround for this or is socat currently broken on Windows?

Comment: This is not a security related question, so it is off topic here. Have you done an internet search of the error? It appears to return some relevant results.

Comment: @multithr3at3d yes I have and did not find anything relevant

Comment: Are you sure? [The first 5 results](https://www.startpage.com/do/search?lui=english&language=english&cat=web&query=socat+couldn%27t+compute+FAST_CWD+pointer) (at least) all seem to point to the same solution.

Comment: @multithr3at3d yea I referenced that solution and how it did not work for me in the original question. It turns out that the issue was unrelated, I posted the answer of how I solved it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I was incorrect, that is just a warning which had no relation to the command failing. The commands actually failed because I was missing an argument (a port to connect to). Once the argument was added it still displayed the warning but proceeded with execution.